# Looking for an HTML editor/workflow that updates as you code

Tags: html, editor, real-time, updating

Just type in the editor and the browsers update as you go. No need to save or switch to the browsers and back.

Any suggestions?

Thanx

Comment: question is not clear,what do you want to do?

and what code do you want to update?

Comment: I'd be typing in an editor with a browser open and visible. As I type tags and text the browser is reloading the page continuously. I've heard of it but I'm having trouble finding it. It involves browser plugins and perhaps a special editor.

Answer (score 3):

http://brackets.io/ seems to offer what you are looking for - but I have no idea how well this works in real life.

For CSS only, have a look at http://livestyle.emmet.io/

This only works with Sublime Text, but offers exactly that: live view of changes.
I haven't tried this out yet myself, but I can at least vouch that Sublime Text is a good editor.

What I prefer to do is use Chrome Workspaces (part of the regular Chrome developer tools) to write changes I make in the browser back to the source files.

I usually limit myself to changes to CSS in the elements view, but you can edit any source file, and the editor that Chrome uses on its Sources tab is serviceable for smaller changes.

An introduction to how Chrome Workspaces function: https://plus.google.com/+AddyOsmani/posts/CYXzDfg3jhC

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ removes the need to save and is my preference, but still requires you to refresh the browser.

I'd claim that due to differences in the rendering engine you should be using one of the major browsers rather than a tool's built in rendering engine as you risk having to refactor much of your code if it's outdated or poorly implemented.

There may be a browser plugin for some of the browsers that refreshes the page for you, but I can imagine this being a bit annoying.. Does it refresh for every keystroke? For every completed word? Every completed tag?

Comment: yes, it refreshes very often. I don't know what it's called or how to find it, but I've heard it exists.

Answer (score 0):

TinCr for Chrome doesn't by default refresh the browser on change, but can be configured to do so easily. You can fine-tune the frequency of changes. Worth noting: it's a Chrome Developer Tool.

[TinCr Documentation](http://tin.cr/docs.html)